# How to reference subproject from root and from itself?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project setup in gradle. There is a root project without any code and then subprojects in subfolders.

```
MyProject
|-build.gradle
|-settings.gradle
|-sub1
  |-build.gradle
  |-settings.gradle
  '-specs/file.xml
|-sub2
'-sub3
```

In `sub1/build.gradle` I reference file.xml as `def file = '$rootDir/specs/file.xml'` so I can build `sub1`.
But when I call a task in `sub1/build.gradle` from the root directory, `$rootDir` seems to refer to the calling root project because `file` is interpreted as `MyProject/specs/file.xml` which doesn't exist.
How can I reference a file in my subproject so that it is resolved the same regardless from where it is called?

Answer (score 0):

The [rootDir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:rootDir) property is always the root of a project (i.e. the outermost one in a multi-project). It doesn't matter from where you call it.

You probably want to use [projectDir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:projectDir) instead.